# ZF: reusing elements across forms

Tags: php, zend-framework

For elements related to addresses, phone numbers, etc..what is the best way to reuse them across forms?  Should I be creating some sort of helper to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @markus notes, you can create custom form elements extending `Zend_Form_Element`.

For the kind of uses you identify - address, phone number - that are likely aggregations of other elements but that still need to be treated as a single entity, check out Matthew Weier O'Phinney's blog post:

[Creating composite elements - phly, boy, phly](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/217-Creating-composite-elements.html)

in which he creates a composite element representing a date composed of three select dropdowns.

An alternative is to create a [subform](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.subforms) to represent one of these entities. The subform class can look like:

```
class My_Form_Subform_Address extends Zend_Form_Subform
{
    public function init()
    {
        // add your elements
    }
}
```

Then add the subform to your main form:

```
$form->addSubform(new My_Form_Subform_Address(), 'address');
```

Answer (score 5):

I would not suggest helpers. I'd just extend the form element class, build my element and add it in whatever form I need it.

```
class Project_Form_Element_PhoneNumber extends Zend_Form_Element
{
    //look at the Zend_Form_Element class, it gives you most of the infrastructure
    //look at how shipped elements are built on top of that class
}
```